# How would I keep a map icon in the same position of the map which is a background image? CSS

Tags: css, image, background, position, background-image

[Map Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQxKh.jpg)

Hi I'm making a map on my website and it needs to have icons on it that can be hovered which means they can't be apart of the actual map image itself.

I'm wondering how I would place the icons on the map and keep them in the same position on the map at different view widths/heights.

This is the CSS for my map background:

```
.background {
position:fixed;
padding:0;
margin:0;

top:0;
left:0;

width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;

background: url("../assets/map.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: 100vw 100vh;
-moz-background-size: 100vw 100vh;
-o-background-size: 100vw 100vh;
background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}
```

The map will change size based on the resolution of the screen which makes it tricky for me to keep the icons in the same place through screen changes. Currently I tried using position absolute and putting it in the right place but as you change the screen so does the placement of the icon.

Am I doing it wrong or is there another solution to this? Thanks.

Comment: You could define the position in percentage. 20% is always 20%, not matter the value in pixel.

Answer (score 1):

if you wanna position icons on a background then you have to give that background container a position relative and then give the elements inside background container a position absolute

```css
body,
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.background {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQxKh.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}

.icon1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #45619D;
}

.icon2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #45619D;
}

.icon3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #4AC144;
}

.icon4 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #45619D;
}

.icon5 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #45619D;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
    <span class="icon1"></span>
    <span class="icon2"></span>
    <span class="icon3"></span>
    <span class="icon4"></span>
    <span class="icon5"></span>
</div>
```